# How to add a second git account to a machine?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I hope this is not a repeat, as I have searched but haven't been able to find a satisfying answer. I connect to a remote Linux machine via ssh. I have a Gitlab account signed in on this machine, including the user.name and user.email as well as ssh key. However, I want to be able to clone and work with a private Github repository that is connected to my separate Github account. Both accounts share the same username and email.

Is the solution as simple as just generating a new ssh and adding it to my Github account? When I try to pull from Github will the machine know which key/account to use?

What's the best way to handle this situation? Thanks for any help

Comment: your remote origin is going to differ between gitlab and github account so all you need is proper credentials. so yeah get an ssh key for your github account and use it in the same machine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+multiple+accounts